# How to deal with semantic version data type in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I know that there is no data type in BigQuery. What would you prefer to deal with semantic versions in BigQuery?

I have the following schema:

```
software:string,
software_version:string
```

software_version column is `string` but the data I store there is in semver format: `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH-prerelease

I especially want to perform operators `<` `>` `=`.

```
select '4.0.0' < '4.0.0-beta'
```

This returns `true`, but according to the semver [definition](https://semver.org/) it's false. Because the char `-` is used for prerelease.

Comment: this actually returns `true` - please double check on your side and clarify!

Comment: Yes it's a typo.. the result should be false :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

You can use `compareSemanticVersion` UDF to compare two semantic versions
and/or use `normaizedSemanticVersion` UDF to sort output via ORDER BY clause.
See example below with both (compare and order by) use cases in one

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION normaizedSemanticVersion(semanticVersion STRING) 
AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(
      IF(isDigit, REPEAT('0', 8 - LENGTH(chars)) || chars, chars), '' ORDER BY grp 
    ) || 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzz' 
  FROM (
    SELECT grp, isDigit, STRING_AGG(char, '' ORDER BY OFFSET) chars,
    FROM (
      SELECT OFFSET, char, isDigit,
        COUNTIF(NOT isDigit) OVER(ORDER BY OFFSET) AS grp
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(semanticVersion, '')) AS char WITH OFFSET, 
      UNNEST([char IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')]) isDigit
    )
    GROUP BY grp, isDigit
)));
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION compareSemanticVersions(
  normSemanticVersion1 STRING, 
  normSemanticVersion2 STRING) 
AS ((
  SELECT CASE 
      WHEN v1 < v2 THEN 'v2 newer than v1'
      WHEN v1 > v2 THEN 'v1 newer than v2'
      ELSE 'same versions'
    END
  FROM UNNEST([STRUCT(
    normaizedSemanticVersion(normSemanticVersion1) AS v1, 
    normaizedSemanticVersion(normSemanticVersion2) AS v2
  )])
));
WITH test AS (
  SELECT '1.10.0-alpha' AS v1 , '1.0.0-alpha.1' AS v2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '4.0.0', '4.0.0-beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.0.0-alpha.1'     , '1.0.0-alpha.beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.0.0-alpha.beta'  , '1.0.0-beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.0.0-beta'        , '1.0.0-beta.2' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.0.0-beta.2'      , '1.0.0-beta.11' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.0.0-beta.11'     , '1.0.0-rc.1' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.0.0-rc.1'        , '1.0.0' UNION ALL
  SELECT '1.0.0-alpha-1.1+build1234-a', '1.0.0-alpha-1.1+build1234-a'
)
SELECT v1, v2, compareSemanticVersions(v1, v2) result
FROM test 
ORDER BY normaizedSemanticVersion(v1)
```

with output

```
Row v1                              v2                              result   
1   1.0.0-alpha-1.1+build1234-a     1.0.0-alpha-1.1+build1234-a     same versions    
2   1.0.0-alpha.1                   1.0.0-alpha.beta                v2 newer than v1     
3   1.0.0-alpha.beta                1.0.0-beta                      v2 newer than v1     
4   1.0.0-beta.2                    1.0.0-beta.11                   v2 newer than v1     
5   1.0.0-beta.11                   1.0.0-rc.1                      v2 newer than v1     
6   1.0.0-beta                      1.0.0-beta.2                    v1 newer than v2     
7   1.0.0-rc.1                      1.0.0                           v2 newer than v1     
8   1.10.0-alpha                    1.0.0-alpha.1                   v1 newer than v2     
9   4.0.0                           4.0.0-beta                      v1 newer than v2
```

Note: I wrote above UDFs based on how I understood Semantic Versioning after reading reference you provided. There are potentially some edge cases that still needs to be addressed. But definitely should work for simple cases and I hope you will be able to simply adopt those UDFs and adjust output for your particular needs and maybe even to optimize the I ended up using here

One more as FYI: in the `normaizedSemanticVersion` UDF I am using `zzzzzzzzzz` just to address some edge-cases. Another option I tried was `..zzzzzzzzzz` (note two extra dots) - I think this gives better result for more complex cases - but I was really out of time to complete testing. Please try

For example, in Semantic Versioning page there is an example: 1.0.0-alpha < 1.0.0-alpha.1 < 1.0.0-alpha.beta < 1.0.0-beta < 1.0.0-beta.2 < 1.0.0-beta.11 < 1.0.0-rc.1 < 1.0.0.

To make this same order as in that example - `..zzzzzzzzzz` should be use - see below

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION normaizedSemanticVersion(semanticVersion STRING) 
AS ((
  SELECT STRING_AGG(
      IF(isDigit, REPEAT('0', 8 - LENGTH(chars)) || chars, chars), '' ORDER BY grp 
    ) || '..zzzzzzzzzzzzzz' 
  FROM (
    SELECT grp, isDigit, STRING_AGG(char, '' ORDER BY OFFSET) chars,
    FROM (
      SELECT OFFSET, char, isDigit,
        COUNTIF(NOT isDigit) OVER(ORDER BY OFFSET) AS grp
      FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(semanticVersion, '')) AS char WITH OFFSET, 
      UNNEST([char IN ('1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','0')]) isDigit
    )
    GROUP BY grp, isDigit
)));
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION compareSemanticVersions(
  normSemanticVersion1 STRING, 
  normSemanticVersion2 STRING) 
AS ((
  SELECT
    CASE 
      WHEN v1 < v2 THEN 'v2 newer than v1'
      WHEN v1 > v2 THEN 'v1 newer than v2'
      ELSE 'same versions'
    END
  FROM UNNEST([STRUCT(
    normaizedSemanticVersion(normSemanticVersion1) AS v1, 
    normaizedSemanticVersion(normSemanticVersion2) AS v2
  )])
));
WITH test AS (
  SELECT 1 `order`, '1.0.0-alpha' version UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '1.0.0-alpha.1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '1.0.0-alpha.beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '1.0.0-beta' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, '1.0.0-beta.2' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, '1.0.0-beta.11' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, '1.0.0-rc.1' UNION ALL
  SELECT 8, '1.0.0.' 
)
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY normaizedSemanticVersion(version)
```

with output that matches Semantic Versioning specification

```
Row order   version  
1   1   1.0.0-alpha  
2   2   1.0.0-alpha.1    
3   3   1.0.0-alpha.beta     
4   4   1.0.0-beta   
5   5   1.0.0-beta.2     
6   6   1.0.0-beta.11    
7   7   1.0.0-rc.1   
8   8   1.0.0.
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not issue of BigQuery. The statement `'4.0.0' < '4.0.0-beta'` will return `True` in all programming languages while this comparison is based on alphabetical order that is not the same like semantic version order.

I recommend to write some custom UDF function that can resolve your issue or try to use SQL like this:

```
with data as (
select "4.0.0" as version
union all select "4.0.0-beta" as version
)
select 
split(d.version,'-')[offset(0)] as version,
case array_length(SPLIT(d.version,'-')) 
  when 1 then NULL
  when 2 then split(d.version,'-')[offset(1)]
end as prerelease
from data as d
order by version asc, prerelease desc
```

of course be careful about comparing versions as well because in this case will comparison not work like you expect

```
with data as (
select "4.0.0" as version
union all select "4.1.0" as version
union all select "4.2.0" as version
union all select "4.10.0" as version
)
select 
split(d.version,'-')[offset(0)] as version,
case array_length(split(d.version,'-')) 
  when 1 then NULL
  when 2 then split(d.version,'-')[offset(1)]
end as patch
from data as d
order by version asc, patch desc
```

Then you have to split versions to "MAJOR","MINOR","PATCH" and compare by every element separately.

Comment: Thanks Jozef, but I wanted to compare the semantic versions not to order

Comment: I understand, but if you want to demonstrate and visualize comparison best way how to it is see ordered results. You can simply write comparison according my sql code.

Comment: ideally best way is to write UDF function where you will split version string to separate parts and then do comparison particulary by these parts. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions